# sort array in RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs

RxJava has a method `toSortedList(Comparator comparator)` that converts a flow of objects into a list of objects sorted by a Comparator.

How can I achieve the same in JavaScript with RxJS and get an Observable with a flow of objects to emit a sorted array/list?

Comment: The same idea: source.toArray().map(x => x.sort())
Take a look https://jsbin.com/leqede/edit?js,console

Comment: I want to get an observable stream of swapping operations.

Answer (score 12):

you can use the code following:

```
Rx.Observable.of(5,8,7,9,1,0,6,6,5).toArray().map(arr=>arr.sort()).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

With rxjs@7.1.0

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obs = of(5,8,7,9,1,0,6,6,5).pipe(
  toArray(),
  map(arr=> arr.sort((a,b) => a - b)
);


obs.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

outputs [0, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9]